# python: return int(value) ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

Help, I keep getting ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base
 10: '' when I try to migrate my models. this is my model

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import date

class PoliceAssurance(models.Model):
     numPolice = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
     raison = models.CharField(max_length=50)
     tel = models.CharField(max_length=20)
     email = models.CharField(max_length=50)
     interlocuteur = models.CharField(max_length=50)
     dateDebut = models.CharField(max_length=50)
     dateFin = models.CharField(max_length=50)
     tiers = models.CharField(max_length=50)
     formule = models.CharField(max_length=50)
     territoire = models.CharField(max_length=50)
     exclusions = models.CharField(max_length=50)
     complement = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

this is the trace

```
Operations to perform:
Apply all migrations: sessions, contenttypes, log, admin, auth
Running migrations:
Rendering model states... DONE
Applying log.0003_auto_20170206_1251...Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 10,in <module> execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py",             line 350, in execute_from_command_line utility.execute()
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 342, in execute self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line  348, in run_from_argv self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 399, in execute output = self.handle(*args, **options) File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 200, in handle executor.migrate(targets,plan, fake=fake,fake_initial=fake_initial)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 92, in migrate self._migrate_all_forwards(plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 121, in _migrate_all_forwards state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 198, in apply_migration state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 123, in apply operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state) File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\fields.py", line 62, in database_forwards field,
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 382, in add_field definition, params = self.column_sql(model, field, include_default=True)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 145, in column_sql default_value = self.effective_default(field)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 210, in effective_default default = field.get_db_prep_save(default, self.connection)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 728, in get_db_prep_save prepared=False)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 968, in get_db_prep_value value = self.get_prep_value(value)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 976, in get_prep_value     return int(value)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Comment: Could you provide the entire stack trace

Comment: @EvansMurithi i included the trace

Answer (score 1):

my problem is solved

i delete the migrations folder and I executed these commands

python manage.py showmigrations App

python manage.py migrate zero

python manage.py makemigrations

python manage.py migrate App and i run the App